# How to create h5py dataset of a dataset

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I am new to HDF5 and I am trying to create a dataset of compound type with three columns: MD5, size, another datset.

How can I achieve this?

I tried following code:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

dbfile = h5py.File("test.h5",'w')
dtype1 = h5py.Dataset('myset', (100,))
dtype2 = np.dtype([
    ('MD5', np.str_, 32),
    ('size', "i8"),
    ('timestep0', dtype1)
    ])
records = dbfile.create_dateset('records', (4,), rec_type)
```

I get the error:

```
typeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

referring to the line:

```
dtype1 = h5py.Dataset('myset', (100,))
```

Comment: What is that `h5py.Dataset()` command supposed to do?  Where is that use documented?  http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#creating-datasets

Comment: I am trying to define a type Dataset. I assumed h5py.Dataset would do it. Part of the problem is that I can't find how to in the documentation.

Comment: I don't understand.  Illustrate with `numpy` arrays, or `HDF5` references what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57667412/how-to-write-data-to-a-compound-data-using-h5py/64099592#64099592

Answer (score 0):

`h5py.Dataset('myset', (100,))` tries to create a `dataset` object directly (invoking it's `__init__`?).  But according to the reference:

http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#reference

```
class Dataset(identifier)

Dataset objects are typically created via Group.create_dataset(), or by
retrieving existing datasets from a file. Call this constructor to
create a new Dataset bound to an existing DatasetID identifier.
```

Even if you could get such an object (which I still don't understand), it isn't going to work in a `np.dtype`.  For example if I replace it with a `datetime.datetime` object, the result is `dtype='O'`

```
In [503]: dtype2 = np.dtype([
     ...:     ('MD5', np.str_, 32),
     ...:     ('size', "i8"),
     ...:     ('timestep0', datetime.datetime)
     ...:     ])

In [504]: dtype2
Out[504]: dtype([('MD5', '<U32'), ('size', '<i8'), ('timestep0', 'O')])
```

In `numpy` dytes there the defined types like strings, ints and floats, and `object` (not list, dict or other Python classes).

I can save a compound dtype to `h5py`, but can't save object dtypes.  There is a `h5py` dtype that gets loaded into a `numpy` object dtype, but it doesn't, in general, work the other direction.

http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/special.html#variable-length-strings

[hdf5 can't write numpy array of object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44156397/hdf5-cant-write-numpy-array-of-object-type)

http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/refs.html  - object refs

```
In [7]: import h5py
In [8]: f = h5py.File('wtihref.h5','w')
In [9]: ds0 = f.create_dataset('dset0',np.arange(10))
In [10]: ds1 = f.create_dataset('dset1',np.arange(11))
In [11]: ds2 = f.create_dataset('dset2',np.arange(12))
In [12]: ds2.ref
Out[12]: <HDF5 object reference>
In [13]: ref_dtype = h5py.special_dtype(ref=h5py.Reference)
In [14]: ref_dtype
Out[14]: dtype('O')
In [16]: rds = f.create_dataset('refdset', (5,), dtype=ref_dtype)
In [17]: rds[:3]=[ds0.ref, ds1.ref, ds2.ref]
In [28]: [f[r] for r in rds[:3]]
Out[28]: 
[<HDF5 dataset "dset0": shape (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), type "<f4">,
 <HDF5 dataset "dset1": shape (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), type "<f4">,
 <HDF5 dataset "dset2": shape (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), type "<f4">]
```

With a compound dtype

```
In [55]: dt2 = np.dtype([('x',int),('y','S12'),('z',ref_dtype)])
In [56]: rds1 = f.create_dataset('refdtype', (5,), dtype=dt2)
In [72]: rds1[0]=(0,b'ONE',ds0.ref)
In [75]: rds1[1]=(1,b'two',ds1.ref)
In [76]: rds1[2]=(2,b'three',ds2.ref)
In [82]: rds1[:3]
Out[82]: 
array([(0, b'ONE', <HDF5 object reference>),
       (1, b'two', <HDF5 object reference>),
       (2, b'three', <HDF5 object reference>)],
      dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('y', 'S12'), ('z', 'O')])
In [83]: f[rds1[0]['z']]
Out[83]: <HDF5 dataset "dset0": shape (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), type "<f4">
```

`h5py` uses the `metadata` property of a `dtype` to store info on the reference:

```
In [84]: ref_dtype.metadata
Out[84]: mappingproxy({'ref': h5py.h5r.Reference})
In [85]: dt2.fields['z']
Out[85]: (dtype('O'), 16)
In [86]: dt2.fields['z'][0].metadata
Out[86]: mappingproxy({'ref': h5py.h5r.Reference})
```