# How to write data to a compound data using h5py?

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I know that in `c` we can construct a compound dataset easily using `struct` type and assign data chunk by chunk. I am currently implementing a similar structure in `Python` with `h5py`.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np 

# we create a h5 file 
f = h5py.File("test.h5") # default is mode "a"


# We define a compound datatype using np.dtype
dt_type = np.dtype({"names":["image","feature"],
                   "formats":[('<f4',(4,4)),('<f4',(10,))]})

# we define our dataset with 5 instances
a = f.create_dataset("test", shape=(5,), dtype=dt_type)
```

To write data, we can do this...

```
# "feature" array is 1D
a['feature']
```

output is

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)

# Write 1s to data field "feature"
a["feature"] = np.ones((5,10))

array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

The problem is when I wrote 2D array "image" into file.

```
a["image"] = np.ones((5,4,4))

ValueError: When changing to a larger dtype, its size must be a divisor of the total size in bytes of the last axis of the array.
```

I read the documentation and did research. Unfortunately, I did not find a good solution. I understand that we apply `group/dataset` to mimic this compound data but I really want to keep this structure. Is there a good way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When I make an array with that shape and dtype, your `ones` assignment works.  Does `a['image'] = np.ones((5,4,4), 'f4')` work?  `np.ones` may be making `float64` by default, and `h5py` is having trouble converting that to `float32`.  Maybe later I'll try it with `h5py`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for your response. It does not work. The `dtype` follows what we define in the beginning. In our case it is `float32` and the type of value assigned will be forced to float32.

Comment: I can create a numpy array with that dtype and shape, set its 'image` field with those  `np.ones`.  And `a[:] = arr` works.   Also `a['image'][:] = np.ones((5,4,4))` works.

Comment: @hpaulj Did you check the value in `a["image"]`? I did that before asking this question. For me, it did not change the values but it runs without error.

Comment: You may have to set the whole array, rather than just one field.  I'm not seeing much in the `h5py` docs about setting compound dtype values.  It shows some ways of fetching the values, beyond what `numpy` allows.

Comment: @hpaulj That s why I am asking here. Maybe there is a low-level API.

Comment: My understanding is that `h5py` uses `cython` code to interface with the `HDF5` `C++` API.  Since numpy arrays can set field values, I suspect the limitation we see here, derives from the HDF5 itself, not from some laziness on the part of the `h5py` developers.

Comment: Yea. That s what I thought too. There are many talented developers here. I just think i may find good solutions by luck. LOL

Comment: With a simpler dtype lilke `np.dtype([('x',int),('y',int)])` I had no problems setting fields or portions of fields.

Comment: Looking at some other examples, we may need to pay more attention to the error message and location.  The `__setitem__` code is Python.  The problem may be limited to 2d fields.  Also `numpy` has made some changes in how it deals with multifield indexing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PyTables (aka tables) to populate your HDF5 file with the desired arrays. You should think of each row as an independent entry (defined by a dtype). So, the 'image' array is stored as 5 (4x4) ndarrays, not a single (5x4x4) ndarray. The same goes for the 'feature' array.

This example adds each 'feature' and 'image' array one row at a time. Alternately, you can create a numpy record array with both arrays with data for multiple rows, then add with a Table.append() function.

See code below to create the file, then open read only to check the data.

```
import tables as tb
import numpy as np 

# open h5 file for writing
with tb.File('test1_tb.h5','w') as h5f:

# define a compound datatype using np.dtype
    dt_type = np.dtype({"names":["feature","image"],
                        "formats":[('<f4',(10,)) , ('<f4',(4,4)) ] })

# create empty table (dataset)
    a = h5f.create_table('/', "test1", description=dt_type)

# create dataset row interator
    a_row = a.row
# create array data and append to dataset
    for i in range(5):
        a_row['feature'] = i*np.ones(10)
        a_row['image'] = np.random.random(4*4).reshape(4,4)
        a_row.append()

    a.flush()

# open h5 file read only and print contents
with tb.File('test1_tb.h5','r') as h5fr:
    a = h5fr.get_node('/','test1')
    print (a.coldtypes)
    print ('# of rows:',a.nrows)

    for row in a:
        print (row['feature'])
        print (row['image'])
```

Answer (score -1):

This blogpost has helped me with this issue:
https://www.christopherlovell.co.uk/blog/2016/04/27/h5py-intro.html

The key code for writing a compound dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

# Load your dataset into numpy
audio = np.load(path.join(root_dir, 'X_dev.npy')).astype(np.float32)
text = np.load(path.join(root_dir, 'T_dev.npy')).astype(np.float32)
gesture = np.load(path.join(root_dir, 'Y_dev.npy')).astype(np.float32)

# open a hdf5 file
hf = h5py.File(root_dir+"/dev.hdf5", 'a') 

# create group
g1 = hf.create_group('dev') 

# put dataset in subgroups
g1.create_dataset('audio', data=audio)
g1.create_dataset('text', data=text)
g1.create_dataset('gesture', data=gesture)

# close the hdf5 file
hf.close()
```